# Camel CXF - operation output unmarshalling error

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, wsdl2java

I have wsdl (i can't change it) - this is required part:

```
<xs:complexType name="out">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="isValid"
                      type="xs:boolean"
                      minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="errorMessage"
                      type="xs:string"
                      minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="GetDataResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return"
                        type="tns:out"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

<message name="GetDataResponseMessage">
    <part name="parameters"
          element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
  </message>

<operation name="GetData">
      <output message="tns:GetDataResponseMessage"/>
    </operation>
```

Generated service (by this wsdl) with wsdl2java:

```
@WebService(...)
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface MyService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetData", action = "...")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetData", targetNamespace = "...", className = "GetData")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetDataResponse", targetNamespace = "..", className = "GetDataResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "return", targetNamespace = "...")
    public Out getData(
        @WebParam(name = "XMLData", targetNamespace = "...")
        Request xmlData,
        @WebParam(name = "MessageID", targetNamespace = "...")
        java.lang.String messageID
    );
}
```

I create CXF endpoint:

```
CxfEndpoint endpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
    endpoint.setAddress("address");
    endpoint.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
    endpoint.setWsdlURL(WSDL_LOCATION);
```

And i call this operation with camel:

```
.setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, namespace())
      .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, operationName())
.to(endpoint)
```

Service return following response body:

```
<m:GetDataResponse xmlns:m="...">
         <m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <isValid>true</isValid>
            <errorMessage>sample error</errorMessage>
         </m:return>
      </m:GetDataResponse>
```

But camel tries to unmarshal this body to Out.class:

> WARN o.a.c.p.PhaseInterceptorChain javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"isValid"). Expected elements are
>   <{...}isValid>,<{...}errorMessage>

If generated service without @ResponseWrapper that everything works fine.

I don't care what type it will be as a result - Out.class or GetDataResponse.class - My main wish is not to write a custom processing of the result in my custom interseptor.

P.S. i deleted all namespaces (they are described correctly but they don't matter)

**Update**

Out.class definition

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "out", propOrder = {
    "isValid",
    "errorMessage"
})
public class Out {

    protected Boolean isValid;
    protected String errorMessage;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the isValid property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isIsValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the isValid property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setIsValid(Boolean value) {
        this.isValid = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the errorMessage property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the errorMessage property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setErrorMessage(String value) {
        this.errorMessage = value;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a String representation of the contents of this type.
     * This is an extension method, produced by the 'ts' xjc plugin
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, JAXBToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should post the definition of "Out" class, it seems like it misses some namespace info.

Comment: yes, there is no information in Out class:     protected Boolean isValid;
    protected String errorMessage;